# typehint only one property of an object and leave other properies to be hinted

Tags: reactjs, typescript, inertiajs

I'm using a hook from inertiajs `useForm` which takes a generic type as follows:

```js
function useForm<TForm extends Record<string, unknown>>(initialValues?: TForm);
```

if i use the hook like this:

```js
useForm({
    id: oldGroup?.id,
    branch_id: oldGroup?.branch_id ?? allowedBranches[0].id,
    department_id: oldGroup?.department_id ?? allowedDepartments[0].id,
    stage: oldGroup?.stage ?? allowedYears[0],
    try: oldGroup?.try ?? allowedTries[0],
    createdAt: oldGroup?.created_at,
    updatedAt: oldGroup?.updated_at,
    secondTry: oldGroup?.tahmeel,
    studentsCount: oldGroup?.students_count,
    departmentId: oldGroup?.department_id,
    _method: undefined,
    excel_file: new File([], ''),
  });
```

then the object type is infered as:

```js
useForm<{
    id: number | undefined;
    branch_id: number;
    department_id: number;
    stage: number;
    try: number;
    createdAt: string | undefined;
    updatedAt: string | undefined;
    secondTry: boolean | undefined;
    studentsCount: number | undefined;
    departmentId: number | undefined;
    _method: undefined;
    excel_file: File;
}>(initialValues?: {
    ...;
} | undefined)
```

which is correct but because the type infered for `_method` is `undefined` then i can't use the methods from the hook to reassign anything to it, I set `_method` as undefined by default but i want to re set it to something else elsewhere,

I can add a generic type for the hook like:

```js
useForm<{
    id: number | undefined;
    branch_id: number;
    department_id: number;
    stage: number;
    try: number;
    createdAt: string | undefined;
    updatedAt: string | undefined;
    secondTry: boolean | undefined;
    studentsCount: number | undefined;
    departmentId: number | undefined;
    _method: 'post' | 'put' | 'get' | 'patch' | undefined;
    excel_file: File;
  }>({
    id: oldGroup?.id,
    branch_id: oldGroup?.branch_id ?? allowedBranches[0].id,
    department_id: oldGroup?.department_id ?? allowedDepartments[0].id,
    stage: oldGroup?.stage ?? allowedYears[0],
    try: oldGroup?.try ?? allowedTries[0],
    createdAt: oldGroup?.created_at,
    updatedAt: oldGroup?.updated_at,
    secondTry: oldGroup?.tahmeel,
    studentsCount: oldGroup?.students_count,
    departmentId: oldGroup?.department_id,
    _method: undefined,
    excel_file: new File([], ''),
  });
```

which is tedious because i only need to type hint one property and i had to type hint the whole object, so now everytime i add a new property i need to add a type to it.

Is there a way to avoid this? can i only type hint one property of the object?

Comment: or you could just annotate `_method` as you want: `_method: undefined as string | undefined` or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to broaden the type:

```js
useForm({
    id: oldGroup?.id,
    branch_id: oldGroup?.branch_id ?? allowedBranches[0].id,
    department_id: oldGroup?.department_id ?? allowedDepartments[0].id,
    stage: oldGroup?.stage ?? allowedYears[0],
    try: oldGroup?.try ?? allowedTries[0],
    createdAt: oldGroup?.created_at,
    updatedAt: oldGroup?.updated_at,
    secondTry: oldGroup?.tahmeel,
    studentsCount: oldGroup?.students_count,
    departmentId: oldGroup?.department_id,
    _method: undefined as 'post' | 'put' | 'get' | 'patch' | undefined,
    excel_file: new File([], ''),
  });
```